# Import class from external lib into react

Tags: reactjs

I'm currentely integrating a webrtc client into the new react-created UI. The client comes as a class including some function for init, communicating with the server-side. Does anyone have any idea about how to import this external resource? I'm a newbee to the frontend, many thanks for any sort of help
I've tried something like this, and browser console indicates OceanaCustomerWebVoiceVideo is not a function:

````
class ClientWrapper extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { scriptStatus: 'no' };
        this.scriptLoaded = this.scriptLoaded.bind(this);
    }

    scriptLoaded(){
        console.log('external resource has been loaded');
        console.log('initialise client');
        var amcConfig = {
            restUrl: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
            port: 'xxx',
            secure: true,
            urlPath: 'xxx/xxx/xxx'
        };

        var aawgConfig = {
            webGatewayAddress: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
            port: 'xxx',
            secure: true
        };
        localStorage.setItem('oceana.amcConfig', JSON.stringify(amcConfig));
        localStorage.setItem('oceana.aawg.config', JSON.stringify(aawgConfig));
        var oceanaConfig = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oceana.amcConfig'));
        var webGatewayConfig = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oceana.aawg.config'));

        var config = {
            configuration: oceanaConfig,
            webGatewayConfiguration: webGatewayConfig
        }
        var clientInstance = new window.OceanaCustomerWebVoiceVideo(config);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const {scriptLoaded} = this.state;
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.async = true;
        script.src = "./OceanaCustomerWebVoiceVideo.js";
        script.onload = ()=>this.scriptLoaded();
        //For head
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
    render() {
        

        return (
            <div >
                <h1>{scriptLoaded}</h1>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
export { ClientWrapper };```
````

Comment: where did you define `OceanaCustomerWebVoiceVideo` variable?

Comment: `window` object do not have built-in `OceanaCustomerWebVoiceVideo` variable.

Comment: yeah, I defined OceanaCustomerWebVoiceVideo in the './OceanaCustomerWebVoiceVideo.js' where I load this script before calling it

Comment: The error is that `OceanaCustomerWebVoiceVideo is not a function`, So how do you define the function?